# Chaining functions of type IO (Maybe a )

Tags: haskell

I am writing a small library for interacting with a few external APIs. One set of functions will construct a valid request to the yahoo api and parse the result to a data type. Another set of functions will look up the users current location based on IP and return a data type representing the current location. While the code works, it seems having to explicitly pattern match to sequence multiple functions of type IO (Maybe a).

```
-- Yahoo API

constructQuery :: T.Text -> T.Text -> T.Text
constructQuery city state = "select astronomy,  item.condition from weather.forecast" <>
                            " where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1)" <>
                            " where text=\"" <> city <> "," <> state <> "\")"

buildRequest :: T.Text -> IO ByteString
buildRequest yql = do
    let root = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql"
        datatable = "store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"
        opts = defaults & param "q" .~ [yql]
                          & param "env" .~ [datatable]
                          & param "format" .~ ["json"]
    r <- getWith opts root
    return $ r ^. responseBody

run :: T.Text -> IO (Maybe Weather)
run yql = buildRequest yql >>= (\r -> return $ decode r :: IO (Maybe Weather))


-- IP Lookup
getLocation:: IO (Maybe IpResponse)
getLocation = do
    r <- get "http://ipinfo.io/json"
    let body = r ^. responseBody
    return (decode body :: Maybe IpResponse)
```

-- Combinator

```
runMyLocation:: IO (Maybe Weather)
runMyLocation = do
    r <- getLocation
    case r of
        Just ip -> getWeather ip
        _ ->  return Nothing
    where getWeather = (run . (uncurry constructQuery) . (city &&& region))
```

Is it possible to thread getLocation and run together without resorting to explicit pattern matching to "get out" of the Maybe Monad?

Answer (score 5):

You can happily nest `do` blocks that correspond to different monads, so it's just fine to have a block of type `Maybe Weather` in the middle of your `IO (Maybe Weather)` block.

For example,

```
runMyLocation :: IO (Maybe Weather)
runMyLocation = do
    r <- getLocation
    return $ do ip <- r; return (getWeather ip)
  where
    getWeather = run . (uncurry constructQuery) . (city &&& region)
```

This simple pattern `do a <- r; return f a` indicates that you don't need the monad instance for `Maybe` at all though - a simple `fmap` is enough

```
runMyLocation :: IO (Maybe Weather)
runMyLocation = do
    r <- getLocation
    return (fmap getWeather r)
  where
    getWeather = run . (uncurry constructQuery) . (city &&& region)
```

and now you see that the same pattern appears again, so you can write

```
runMyLocation :: IO (Maybe Weather)
runMyLocation = fmap (fmap getWeather) getLocation
  where
    getWeather = run . (uncurry constructQuery) . (city &&& region)
```

where the outer `fmap` is mapping over your `IO` action, and the inner `fmap` is mapping over your `Maybe` value.

---

I misinterpreted the type of `getWeather` (see comment below) such that you will end up with `IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe Weather)))` rather than `IO (Maybe Weather)`.

What you need is a "join" through a two layer monad stack. This is essentially what a monad transformer provides for you (see @dfeuer's answer) but it is possible to write this combinator manually in the case of `Maybe` -

```
import Data.Maybe (maybe)

flatten :: (Monad m) => m (Maybe (m (Maybe a))) -> m (Maybe a)
flatten m = m >>= fromMaybe (return Nothing)
```

in which case you can write

```
runMyLocation :: IO (Maybe Weather)
runMyLocation = flatten $ fmap (fmap getWeather) getLocation
  where
    getWeather = run . (uncurry constructQuery) . (city &&& region)
```

which should have the correct type. If you are going to chain multiple functions like this, you will need multiple calls to `flatten`, in which case it maybe be easier to build a monad transformer stack instead (with the caveat's in @dfeuer's answer).

There is probably a canonical name for the function I've called "flatten" in the transformers or mtl libraries, but I can't find it at the moment.

Note that the function `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` essentially does the case analysis for you, but abstracts it into a function.

Comment: Appreciate the response, however this results in a function with of type: runMyLocation:: IO (Maybe (IO (Maybe Weather))).  Any way to avoid the nesting of IO (Maybe (IO Maybe v)) ?

Comment: Apologies, I misread the type of `getWeather` to be `IpResponse -> Weather` rather than `IpResponse :: IO (Maybe Weather)`. I'll provide a clarifying edit.

Answer (score 3):

Some consider this an anti-pattern, but you could use `MaybeT IO a` instead of `IO (Maybe a)`. The problem is that you only deal with one of the ways `getLocation` can fail—it could also throw an `IO` exception. From that perspective, you might as well drop the `Maybe` and just throw your own exception if decoding fails, catching it wherever you like.

Comment: By the way, why is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: @Yuuri, because it makes it look like you'll always get a result or `Nothing`, but you might get, say, a network timeout exception.

Comment: I don't see why you think it looks like “always a result of `Nothing`”. Most Haskellers should be familiar enough with monad transformers to know how they work “inside out”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I was certain I'd read a diatribe against that style, but I can't seem to find it. I haven't really found my own favorite error handling approach yet--they all seem to suck differently (and the same is true across all languages).

Answer (score 0):

change getWeather to have `Maybe IpResponse->IO..` and use `>>=` to implement it and then you can do `getLocation >>= getWeather`. The `>>=` in getWeather is the one from Maybe, that will deal with Just and Nothing and the other `getLocation>>= getWeather` the one from IO.
you can even abstract from Maybe and use any `Monad: getWeather :: Monad m -> m IpResponse -> IO ..` and will work.

Comment: I'm not sure  what you're trying to say here, but whatever it is seems to be missing.

Comment: change getWeather to have Maybe IpResponse->IO.. and use >>= to implement it and then you can do getLocation >>= getWeather. The >>= in getWeather is the one from Maybe, that will deal with Just and Nothing and the other getLocation>>= getWeather the one from IO

Comment: You can edit your answer to include this suggestion. I don't personally like it, but it's legitimate. As it stands, your answer is not an answer.

Comment: I agree it's not elegant, but i don't like also your suggestion, to use transfomers just for this case. Anyway.

Comment: with my suggestion you can even abstract from Maybe. getWeather :: Monad m -> m IpResponse -> IO .. and will work